# How does ts treat each item of an array as the key of an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object whose desired type is that its' key is every item in the array and its' value is `any`. What do I do?

I didn't find the answer

example:

```ts
const arr = [100, 4, 200, 1,2] 
const obj = {
  100:xx,
  4:xx,
  1:xx,
  2:xx
}
```

just like this. Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to make each item of an array the ts type of the object's key, I want to define a ts type where the key is each item of the array and the value is of any type,

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the relevant information and your attempt in TypeScript.

Comment: Does an approach like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4VxXN) work for you? If so, I can write it up as an answer with explanation and links to documentation. If not: what am I missing?

Comment: type Test<T extends any[]> = {
        [K in keyof T[number]]: {
            index: number,
            value:number,
            checked:boolean
        }
        
    }
  const num = [1,2,3]
    const map:Test<typeof nums>= {}
I tried this，but no good ts type hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr0 = [1, 99, 'foo', 'bar'] as const;

type Test<T extends readonly unknown[], U = any> = { [P in T[number & keyof T] & PropertyKey]: U };

const test: Test<typeof arr0> = {
    1: 2,
    99: 'string',
    foo: null,
    bar: Symbol(),
    // @ts-expect-error - 'nonExist' does not exist in type
    nonExist: 0,
};
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQBhgXhgbQIwBoYCcB+A5AGYggmkBGiJAuvBDKJFANwBQXUAngAcApjAAqQ6AB5RMIQA8oQsABMWCIXGXgANnxgBXMAGswIAO5hMDfAFV08MHwB89gN5YACjACWYMZjB9AFsaIQQYADIYIyE+EDIxJiiPBBBhBH4AaViGAC4YOwBfbi42aBhFaHzxKX5hePgkZBcMVy4YDphsfIAmXHbOonySaARfAHNqAY6KEHzA7W1+zpg6BHyAZT4QkG0ACgBKZc6AehOYAAEoCABaeWFgKDukEHCbmBJTMABROW9oEgwLQSGCmWDyf6wXwVQRCaag8C-SH5ZD9YpcIA)
hope it helps